# Vertical side menu that overlays body area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have been trying to find some sample code or help on a way to have a vertical menu bar down the left hand side of the page that displays an icon and on hover of the image the menu will expand and overlay the background of the body and display what the icon represents.

I have a little demo here that I found and I like alot, but this is abit more advanced but the basic idea can be seen.

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-wahmenu/full_screen_preview/5533383

As you can see when you hover over some of the icons a small box will overlay the body and this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: you shouuld use css3 animations and absolute positioning to acheive this. i will try to upload some code

Comment: i am working on the code and it looks good, i will upload it soon

Comment: @IPADDRESS Thats fine, thanks for your time

Comment: i have come accross a problem which i am trying to debugg but i should have the code uploaded in 45 mins

Comment: @IPADDRESS Ok, thats fine.

Comment: i have this simple problem but i cant get my head around it. how would i change the width of a parent element on hover. when i find that out the code is ready to show

Comment: you can check the one i already have on my website just click the logo @ http://codinghacked.meximas.com

Comment: @IPADDRESS I will check out your website now :)

Comment: please check out my latest answer

Comment: please check out my latest answer and credit it with and up-vote and class it as the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the code at this url http://jsbin.com/yiyenadi/1/ .

As you can see I did not animate it because this would take more time but it can be done.
Please message me back if you need more help. And please comment your views back.

[EDIT]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>side bar</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

```
<style type="text/css">

   body {
margin:0px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 214);
  }

 #side_bar_container {
width:50px;
background-color: #555C66;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
transition:.5s;
 }

 .line_container{
height:50px;
background-color: #555C66;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

 #line_container1{
border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18)   
 }
 .line_image{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
border-radius: 16px;
color: white;
 }

  .line_text{
margin-top: 16px;/*depends on other values*/
font-size:18px;
width:300px;
height:50px;
float: left;
color: black;
font-family: sans-serif;
position: relative;
z-index: -3px;
  }

   #logo {
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .sidebar_loader{
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
display: ; /*very very important*/
z-index: -3;
position: absolute; /*works with fixed - absolute is experimantal*/
left: 50px;
top: 0px;
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
display: none;
transition: .5s;
 }

  #texter {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
 }

 /*the power starts here*/
 #line_container1:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

  #line_container2:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

 #line_container3:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

 #line_container4:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

 #sidebar_loader1:hover < #line_container1 {
background-color: red;
 }
 /*more*/
 #line_container1:hover ~ #sidebar_loader1 {
z-index: -2;
 }

  #line_container2:hover ~ #sidebar_loader2 {
z-index: -2;
   }

  #line_container3:hover ~ #sidebar_loader3 {
z-index: 2;
   }

  #line_container4:hover ~ #sidebar_loader3 {
z-index: 2;
 }


 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="side_bar_container">

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color:black;" id="logo" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='none';"></div>



<div class="line_container"  id="line_container1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
    <img src="http://www.maxwellmcmahon.com/img/source.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        HTML5/JAVASCRIPT CODES
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container1').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container1').style.background=''">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 1</span>
</div>

<div class="line_container"  id="line_container2" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
    <img src="1.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image" id="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        VIDEOS
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader2" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container2').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container2').style.background=''">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 2</span>

</div>


<div class="line_container" id="line_container3" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
    <img src="http://www.ejprescott.com/media/icons/tools-equipment.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        SETTINGS
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader3" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container3').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container3').style.background=''">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 3</span>
</div>


<div class="line_container" id="line_container4" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519591-089_Speechbubble2-128.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        Forum
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader4" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container4').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container4').style.background='';">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 4</span>
</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('side_bar_container').style.display='none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='none';" title="close this navigation pane" style="width:50px;">X</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want and I will animate the bar at the side I just couldn't get around the first phase, helped alot! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>side bar</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

```
<style type="text/css">

   body {
margin:0px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 214);
  }

 #side_bar_container {
width:50px;
background-color: #555C66;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
transition:.5s;
 }

 .line_container{
height:50px;
background-color: #555C66;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

 #line_container1{
border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18)   
 }
 .line_image{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
border-radius: 16px;
color: white;
 }

  .line_text{
margin-top: 16px;/*depends on other values*/
font-size:18px;
width:300px;
height:50px;
float: left;
color: black;
font-family: sans-serif;
position: relative;
z-index: -3px;
  }

   #logo {
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .sidebar_loader{
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
display: ; /*very very important*/
z-index: -3;
position: absolute; /*works with fixed - absolute is experimantal*/
left: 50px;
top: 0px;
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
display: none;
transition: .5s;
 }

  #texter {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
 }

 /*the power starts here*/
 #line_container1:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

  #line_container2:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

 #line_container3:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

 #line_container4:hover{
background-color: rgb(69,75,83);
 }

 #sidebar_loader1:hover < #line_container1 {
background-color: red;
 }
 /*more*/
 #line_container1:hover ~ #sidebar_loader1 {
z-index: -2;
 }

  #line_container2:hover ~ #sidebar_loader2 {
z-index: -2;
   }

  #line_container3:hover ~ #sidebar_loader3 {
z-index: 2;
   }

  #line_container4:hover ~ #sidebar_loader3 {
z-index: 2;
 }


 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="side_bar_container">

<div style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color:black;" id="logo" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='none';"></div>



<div class="line_container"  id="line_container1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
    <img src="http://www.maxwellmcmahon.com/img/source.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        HTML5/JAVASCRIPT CODES
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container1').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container1').style.background=''">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 1</span>
</div>

<div class="line_container"  id="line_container2" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader1').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
    <img src="1.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image" id="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        VIDEOS
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader2" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container2').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container2').style.background=''">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 2</span>

</div>


<div class="line_container" id="line_container3" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader2').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
    <img src="http://www.ejprescott.com/media/icons/tools-equipment.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        SETTINGS
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader3" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container3').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container3').style.background=''">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 3</span>
</div>


<div class="line_container" id="line_container4" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='block';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';document.getElementById('sidebar_loader3').style.display='none';" onmouseout="">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519591-089_Speechbubble2-128.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        Forum
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader4" onmouseover="document.getElementById('line_container4').style.background='rgb(69,75,83)';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='none';document.getElementById('line_container4').style.background='';">
    <span id="texter">TEST for 4</span>
</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('side_bar_container').style.display='none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sidebar_loader4').style.display='none';" title="close this navigation pane" style="width:50px;">X</button>
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsbin.com/zoguqezu/1. Click the edit button in the top right hand corner to see the code and edit it.

Comment: Thanks this looks right, but a few things first is it possible to start with just the icon and then when you hover over the icon it then enlarges with the icons information. Also when you are hovered over the icons information box that pops out it should stay on that box and let you move around and not go off?